# A list in a list?

Tags: android, list

I have some troubles with a issue in my Android App. Hope someone can help me to solve this.

I have two lists. One list with **Skills** and one list with **employees**.

What I want is a list per **Skill** with all **employees** who have that **skill**.

I thought about this:

**List SkillsWithEmployees**

```
Skill 1 -> (Employee1, Employee2 and Employee3)
Skill 2 -> (Employee2 and Employee3)
Skill 3 -> (Employee1, Employee4 and Employee5)
```

Have someone an solution for me how I can do this? Or maybe other ideas to do something like this?

My result have to be that I can ask "I want all employees with Skill 2"

Comment: HashMap of ArrayList

Comment: Use a MultiMap of some sort, or Make `skill()` a field in your `Employee` class and add it when it's instantiated (or create a `SkilledEmployee` class that contains both `skill` and `employee` fields)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Kkba's answer, a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is probably your best way of organising your data, if you are grouping subsections of employees by skill. As each skill is unique, it can be used as the key part of the `HashMap` like so:

```
HashMap<Skill, Employee> skillMap = new HashMap();

skillMap.put(firstSkill, Arrays.asList(employee1, employee3);
skillMap.put(secondSkill, Arrays.asList(employee2, employee3);
skillMap.put(thirdSkill, Arrays.asList(employee1, employee2, employee4);
```

And the list of employees using a certain skill can be accessed with:

```
skillMap.get(firstSkill);   // Returns employee1 and employee3
```

But keep in mind that `get()` returns `null` if the key does not exist. You may want to use

```
skillmap.getOrDefault(emptySkill, Collections.emptyList());
```

instead to ensure a `List` is always returned regardless of if the skill exists.

Further reading: [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), [`HashMap.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this in a couple ways. Using a `Map<Skill, List<Employee>>` is perfectly fine so long as you don't intend to modify your collection. If you do however, then it can quickly become a pain to add new keys and values.

With that in mind, if you want to have a mutable collection type, then I would use some form of `MultiMap`. The standard Java SDK doesn't include an implementation, but you can find one easily enough online (a proto-implementation is present in the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)), or supplied via a library (i.e. Guava's [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html))

Alternatively, create a class that pairs Skills to Employees, and filter a collection of them based on a predicate. For example:

```
class SkilledEmployee {
    private final Skill skill;
    private final Employee employee;

    SkilledEmployee(Skill skill, Employee employee) {
       this.skill = skill;
       this.employee  = employee;
    }

    Skill skill() {
        return skill;
    }

    Employee employee() {
        return employee;
    }
}

// To find employees by skill, using Java 8...

listOfSkilledEmployees.stream()
    .filter(se -> se.skill().equals(SKILL_ONE)) //Filter out employees with Skill1
    .map(SkilledEmployee::employee)
    .forEach(employeeWithSkillOne -> { /*Do something */});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

"Skill1", ArrayList<"Employee1", "Employee2", "Employee3">
"Skill2", ArrayList<"Employee2", "Employee3">
"Skill3", ArrayList<"Employee1", "Employee4", "Employee5">
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some more context around your answer? An explanation as to **how** it answers the question? Also, it's worth pointing out that this is pseudocode as this will not compile in Java.